# HTML - How do I prevent this <div> linebreak?

Tags: html, tags, line, break

In HTML, how do I prevent this "linebreak" when using the `<div>` tag?

**Example:**

```
<div class="menu"><a href="URL"><br><br>menu</a></div>
<div class="apple"><a href="URL"><br><br>apple</a></div>
```

**Visual example:**

[image: Visual example]

How do I make it so that **apple** appears directly to the *right* of **menu**? I can't seem to do that successfully; **apple** always appears to be below **menu**

**NOTE:** Pretend that **'apple'** is inside its own *invincible* maroon box.

Comment: Nevermind, got it!    `<div class="menu"><a href="URL"><br><br>menu</a><span class="youtube"><a href="URL"><br><br>youtube</a></div>`

Answer (score 1):

When using `<span>` instead of `<div>`, you need to get rid of the line breaks (`<br>`).

If using inline CSS (which is the style attribute), you may want to add `style = "float:left;"` to the first div only. This way:

```
<div class="menu" style="float:left;"><a href="URL"><br><br>menu</a></div>
<div class="apple"><a href="URL"><br><br>apple</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your CSS to include the following;

```
div.menu, div.apple {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You might also need to set the width of each to less than 50%.

Comment: How would I do that, in HTML though?

Comment: @Smith You can add `style="float:left;"` as an attribute to both `div` elements. eg `<div class="menu" style="float:left;">`

Comment: `<div class="menu" style="float:left;"><a href="URL"><br><br>menu</a></div>
<div class="apple" style="float:left;"><a href="URL"><br><br>apple</a></div>`    So like this? Just tried it and got the same result. Trying to get it like this: ![(http://i.imgur.com/uMsn2Lp.png)][1]

Comment: In which case add `display:inline-block;` so you now have; `style="float:left; display:inline-block;"`

Comment: `<div class="menu" style="float:left; display:inline-block;"><a href="URL"><br><br>menu</a></div><div class="apple" style="float:left; display:inline-block;"><a href="URL"><br><br>apple</a></div>` Not sure if I did it correctly, but I still end up with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two block elements that you would like to display side by side?
Have you tried using the "display: inline-block;" property in your css yet?

Comment: Yes, side by side. And as stated, I'm working this out with HTML only and not CSS; I'm trying to get this outcome without getting the CSS involved.

Comment: Ah okay, is there a reason you can't use a span instead of a div then?
A span is an inline element vs. a block element (like div).

Comment: I tried using <span>, but I couldn't get it to work. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong? How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="menu"><a href="URL"><br><br>menu</a><span class="youtube"><a href="URL"><br><br>youtube</a></div>`